# What happens after crashing in a commercial flight simulator?

Tags: accidents, flight-simulator

If you crash in a commercial flight simulator (the type used to train airline pilots), what happens? Do you get a pop-up window in front of you saying "You have crashed"? Does it just show the last scene from before the crash until the simulation is reset? Does it just turn off?

Comment: Answered here for at least one system https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/88461/60886, and a reason for not actually crashing https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/87283/60886

Comment: You will survive!

Comment: It probably says 'go talk to your training captain'

Comment: Tom Scott crashed a B737MAX in a professional simulator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaOvtL6qYpc (from 16:30) and the screen went red...

Comment: Personally I believe you have to pay the drinks. :-)

Comment: Your mind dies as in the Matrix. Tough but fair -- this is why pilots used to make the big bucks.

Comment: In the B-52 WSTs a loud klaxon went off in the building, to embarrass you.

Comment: After the simulator crashes, you fix it by turning it off and back on again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All that happens (in the Level D CRJ machine I trained in) is the visuals black out, there is a sort of crash sound effect, the machine freezes in place momentarily, then returns to its level docking position. The instructor has to do a reset procedure at his controls to get it back in business.

When doing V1 cuts (engine failure during rotation) for the first time, it's not uncommon for pilots new to swept wing jets to crash the rig, because with swept wings the roll rate generated by a large yaw, that is uncorrected with rudder in time, will have you in a 45 <sup>o</sup> bank before you know it and the wing tip will hit the ground.

Answer (score 7):

Airline pilots can train in a variety of certified simulators but you are likely thinking of the [full motion level D simulators](https://simpleflying.com/level-d-simulator/). In some cases its just some [bad graphics of bouncing as seen here](https://youtu.be/_7y7WVW0qLM?t=614) or other [unrealistic crash dynamics](https://youtu.be/QpagUImL_uI?t=858).

Here is some info on [what happens if a pilot does it during real ATP training](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90222/what-happens-after-a-professional-unintentionally-crashes-in-a-simulator-can-th).

Answer (score 1):

Yes infact you do get a popup window of the type you mention on the instructors panel.
Depending on the severity of the crash the visual and  motion may freeze or continue and mostly need some sort of reset.